# Blazor wiping route parameter OnInitializedAsync

Tags: .net, blazor

1. SetParametersAsync Name: Id
2. SetParametersAsync Value: e4b049b4-0f21-41d5-8fd2-b3439fdd5b58
3. **OnInitializedAsync OnInit called with ID: e4b049b4-0f21-41d5-8fd2-b3439fdd5b58
4. **OnInitializedAsync OnInit called with ID: null**

When I use NavigationManager.NavigateTo in my Blazor Server project to navigate to a component with a routeparameter like

@page "/deal/{Id}/edit", the Id parameter is **wiped to null** on the **second call** to OnInitializedAsync.

NavigateTo Method:

```
public void EditDeal()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/deal/{dealId}/edit");
    }

<a @onclick="EditDeal"
```

OnInitializedMethod:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"OnInitializedAsync OnInit called with ID: {Id}");
    if (Id == null)
    {
        dealInformation = dealInformation.SetDefaults();
    }
    else
    { // Get from DB
        dealInformation = await DealService.Get(Id);
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the Server rendering from ServerPrerendered to Server with no luck, and have been stuck for hours.

Thanks!

Comment: How does ur NavigateTo method look? A bit more code would be useful.

Comment: Just updated @Rowin

Comment: There shouldn't be a second call to OnInitializedAsync - you'll need to share the code - but also Why are you using an anchor tag that way? why not set the `href`?

Comment: `OnInitialized`, as the name says, runs after initialization but before parameters are set. Use `OnParametersSet` instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos according to the console logs, OnInitialized is ran after SetParametersAsync, why would I need to call OnParametersSet again if oninitialized is setting my parameter to null?

Comment: @MisterMagoo how would you recommend using the dynamic href with <a>

Comment: @user2205904 then your code or logging is wrong. And no, `OnInitialized` isn't setting anything unless *you* write the code. `null` is the default value for every reference type. `null` means the properties haven't been initialized yet. The fact you see `OnInitialized` running twice means something weird is going on  - creating multiple components perhaps? Reloading the same page?

Comment: @user2205904 besides, you aren't supposed to modify `SetParametersAsync`. That's the method that actually sets the parameters. After that, the runtime will call the appropriate callback. What does your `SetParametersAsync` do?

Comment: SetParametersAsync isn't defined in my component.. sorry am still new to Blazor somewhat.

Comment: Does it matter that I have two routes setup?

Comment: @Pan@page "/deal/{Id}/edit"
@page "/deal/create"

Comment: This is considered a querystring parameter? All of my other endpoint parameters work fine with this structure

Comment: I am populating {Id} in the Navigation manager with the parameter of another component

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos from the source code : https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components/ComponentBase.cs,b3aa26c6030e2079,references
/// <summary>
/// Method invoked when the component is ready to start, having received its
/// initial parameters from its parent in the render tree.
/// </summary>
protected virtual void OnInitialized()

Comment: "how would you recommend using the dynamic href with <a>" : `@if ( dealId != null ) { <a href=@($"/deal/{dealId}/edit")>Edit</a> }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your only showing us some of your code here's my test setup for your issue which works as expected.

`GUIDRouteComponent.razor`

```
@page "/deal/{Id:guid}/edit"

<h3>GUID Route Component</h3>
<div class="p-2 m-2">
    @this.Id
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And my Index page:

```
@page "/Index"
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.GoToDeal">Go to Deal</button>
</div>
<div class="p-2">
    <a href="/deal/e4b049b4-0f21-41d5-8fd2-b3439fdd5b58/edit"> Go to Deal</a>
</div>


@code {
    [Inject] private NavigationManager? NavManager { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => base.OnInitialized();

    private void GoToDeal()
        => this.NavManager?.NavigateTo("/deal/e4b049b4-0f21-41d5-8fd2-b3439fdd5b58/edit");
}
```

You say "the Id parameter is wiped to null on the second call to OnInitializedAsync."  If you are navigating within your app;lication there should be no second call.  This only occurs on the initial page load.